# What is a method for sharing an Aperture library?

Tags: sharing, aperture

As a group (work, family,...), you produce an Aperture library on your computer.

Others (spouse, coworker...) in the group now want to access and edit this library from other computers.

Any solutions?

Comment: Be wary of using such pejoratives with the anticipated audience here, especially when added to that fact that you are *asking for help* ;)  Also, be mindful of understanding the principles of such wonderful sounding soundbites - the "lock-in" meme would only really be suitable if, once you have started using Aperture, you could not *stop* using Aperture.  As it stands, it's merely a tool you can choose to use as a paid piece of software, and you are welcome to export and use your photos in the tool of your choice, *sans lock-in*, at any point.

Comment: I have removed the lock-in comment as it is not key to my question.  Lock-in here referred to all the work that went into managing my picture which I do not think I can recover even using iPhoto, let alone a not mack product.  To avoid loosing this work (sorting, tagging, face recognition, non-destructive editing...), I have to continue using Aperture.  Admittedly, this is opinion, so again I have removed the unnecessary comment.

Comment: Wohoo!  iPhoto now opens Aperture libraries!  I learned my lesson, whining is productive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the library file in a folder that is accessible to other computers and set permissions so that it can be accessed/edited by other users. You also need to be certain that only one person is editing the file at any given time – the software isn't designed as a shared database and I don't know what, if any, protections it provides against this scenario.

You can also use *referenced* images instead of *managed* and put **those** images in a shared space. **However**, other users will only have access to the master images and you will want to beware of external edits that are *destructive* to those master files. Changes to that file hierarchy itself (file moves, renames, etc) made outside of *Aperture* will result in *broken links* and you'll have to relocate the images from inside Aperture. . I prefer the simplicity, security and *beauty* of a *managed* library.

*In what way is this* lock-in? It's a simple case of access to a database file. Granted the file — a *sparse bundle* containing images, metadata and edit instructions in which your master images are stored in their original format — is proprietary to *Aperture* but the master files remain available should you *lose* Aperture for some reason.

[image: screen shot of Contextual Menu option to Show Package Contents of Aperture Library]

*Accessing the files contained within the Aperture Library package using a right (control)-click*

[image: screen shot showing contents of Aperture Library package including master image]

*Inside the library bundle your master images are filed, hierarchically by import date, in their original format. They can be copied out as you wish.*

I fail to see this as an example of Apple *forcing* the eco system on you. You are not forced to use *Aperture* if you don't like it's features and limitations and departure is a simple *export* (of versions and masters) or "unbundling" of the library file (masters only) away.

*Beautiful indeed.*

Comment: Good points, remember that Aperture is a personal photo management system that costs £50.  It's not really intended to be usable as a professional solution for collaborative photo management with other users.  Tools exist for export and even sync of select photos, but the Database file itself is designed for use by a single person at a time, running a local copy of the program, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It is intended as a professional solution – iPhoto is the personal solution – but it isn't designed for collaboration or multi-users.

Comment: I'd argue more "home enthusiast", their own description steers clear of using the word Professional other than to describe available themes and image effects.  It describes it as "Designed for iPhoto users who want to get more from their photos"

Comment: Originally sold for $500, then reduced to $199 prior to availability on App Store,  and aimed squarely at professionals. I'd argue that the wording is aimed at expanding the market rather than fundemental changes to the software.